# Bitbucket Pipelines limit trigger to branches

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to limit certain step to specific branches

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    '{feature/*,release/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*}':
      - step: # Generates credential needed for test and building
          script:
            - echo "All branch, this step is needed for release"
      - parallel:
          script: # Some lint and unit test script
            - echo "All branch, this step is needed for release step"
    '{release/*}':
      - step: # Actual test and build script
          script:
            - echo "Only in release branch"
```

In the above sample I want the first step to run in almost all branch, but the second step should only execute for `release` branches pattern. Unfortunately the actual result was the first step only works in branches like`hotfix` and never gets trigger in `release/version-name` when branching out. How is it supposedly done? Basically the idea is to reuse the first two steps above on **release** branches, so no need to duplicate those steps.

Comment: Some methods will depend on what Bitbucket does with the yaml it reads, and since I don't use Bitbucket I can't begin to guess what they do there. You can, however, use a different yaml feature here: anchors and aliases. See, e.g., https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/yaml-anchors/

Comment: BTW, as they note, indentation in yaml can be quite tricky. I find it helpful to write little one-off Python bits to read and display yaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to do it with YAML anchors

```
definitions:
  steps:
      - step: &key-generator # Generates credential needed for test and building
          name: Generating Key
          script:
            - echo "All branch, this step is needed for release"
      - parallel: &lint-test
          name: Lint check
          script: # Some lint and unit test script
            - echo "All branch, this step is needed for release step"
pipelines:
  branches:
    '{feature/*,release/*,hotfix/*,bugfix/*}':
      - step: *key-generator # YAML anchor referer
      - parallel: *lint-test # YAML anchor referer
    '{release/*}':
      - step: *key-generator # YAML anchor referer
      - parallel: *lint-test # YAML anchor referer
      - step: # Actual test and build script
          script:
            - echo "Only in release branch"
```